How do I exhibit the character Ň (U+0147) in my Word 2010? Why the method described in the first paragraph below doesn't work for this character?
As far as I can understand, to exhibit a Unicode code point in Word, one should press the Alt key, followed by the character +  and the Unicode code point, both typed in the numeric keypad. That’s what I did with the two characters below. And it worked fine.
٪ U066A ARABIC PERCENT SIGN
ٮ U066E ARABIC LETTER DOTLESS BEH
However, when I try to exhibit the character Ň shown in the picture below,

without using the dialog box, but by typing Alt+0147, using the technique mentioned above in the first paragrah, I get the character “  instead, which has the Unicode code point U+201C. To obtain the character Ň, I have to type Alt+ with the + character typed in the numeric keypad and the code point 0147 typed in the normal keypad. Voilà:
Ň
Further, I know that the character “ is present in the code page 1252, which is my Windows code page, with the decimal value 147.
But I still have no idea, what is the logic behind all this? More specifically, why the short cut Alt+0147 in the numeric keypad doesn't work, as expected?

Edit
Please open this document in my OneDrive to verify that Word 365 (free version) correctly exhibits the character Ň, when I type the shortcut Alt+0147, with the characters "+0147" typed in the numeric keypad. Note also that I used the same technique here in this post to exhibit the character Ň. Therefore, I must conclude that my Word 2010 has a bug, and this answers my question.
See also item (2) in this answer.

The answer for Office of how to type this Unicode character
is simple :
Type 0147 inside the text and then press
Alt+X.
The typed text will be replaced by Ň.
Reference :
Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters.
The Alt mechanism you describe is general for Windows,
while the above is specific to Office.

That's a workaround, but doesn't answer the question why the general Windows method doesn't work in Office.

@GuntramBlohm: The only recourse is to ask Microsoft via the Feedback Hub. The "why" may be a bug.

@harrymc See my edit above under Edit. I can even type the character Ň here now,  using the Alt+0147 technique when the characters "+0147" are typed in the numeric keypad, which tells me that this is certainly a bug in Word 2010.

@Belloc: This was one of the first things I tried on Word 365 before I wrote my answer. But it behaved exactly the same as non-keypad characters. Seems that the bug has not been fixed in Word 365 but has become instead more extensive.

@harrymc: you wrote "But it behaved exactly the same as non-keypad characters." That is not what I found out about the matter. If you look at the documents, I mentioned in my Edit above, you´ll verify that the character Ň is printed correctly  in Office 365 and everywhere else I tried, with just one single exception of Word 2010, which prints the character  “ instead. Thus, my conclusion that Word 2010 has a bug in this case.

It didn't happen for me. Perhaps my setup is somewhat different. Maybe even a question of the keyboard.

@harrymc Haven't you forgotten to update the Windows registry, as described in the item (2) in this answer in "superuser"?

Yes, I didn't do that in my new computer (and your link leads to a duplicate post where I have an answer that says just that). However, even after a reboot my Office 365 stubbornly ignores this setting, so not guaranteed to work in all contexts. Entering "Alt 327" or "Alt + 327" both get me Ň. The conclusion is that the difference in input is caused by the handling of the entered number as either decimal or hex, and whether the EnableHexNumpad fix works or not.

Because backward compatibility.
“Alt codes” are older than Windows. They started out on the IBM PC in 1980 (or maybe a little later, I don't know if the feature was present in the original PC). That computer had a character encoding with 256 code points (single-byte encoding). Most programs used a text mode display, capable of displaying in a single, fixed-width, 256-character font supplied by the graphics card called a code page. The default code page on the PC was CP437, which included ASCII as well as diacritics and punctuation characters for mostly Western European languages, a few mathematical and technical symbols, and line drawing characters. The firmware provided with the computer (BIOS) translated presses of Alt+numpad digits into the corresponding character, to allow people to input characters that were not present on the keyboard. For example, Alt+(NumPad1 NumPad6 NumPad5) inserted character 165, which in CP437 is Ñ.
Later Windows came along. With a graphical environment, line drawing characters were not useful, and you could switch between multiple fonts in the same document. So Windows had different character sets (often known as “ANSI code pages” although they didn't actually follow ANSI standards) which omitted those characters to make room for more characters commonly used in text. These were still (except in Asian editions of Windows) single-byte character sets, originally ISO 8859 (e.g. ISO 8859-1 a.k.a. Latin-1 for Western European languages), later extended to “Windows code pages” such as Windows-1252. Windows extended Alt codes to support the Windows code pages while remaining compatible with the habits of users who had learned the “DOS” (really BIOS) code points. So for example, assuming default settings with CP437 as the DOS code page and 8859-1 or Windows-1252 as the Windows code page, Alt+(NumPad1 NumPad6 NumPad5) would still insert ñ from CP437, but if you typed a 0 before the number, you'd get the number from the Windows code page: Alt+(NumPad0 NumPad1 NumPad6 NumPad5) for ¥, Alt+(NumPad0 NumPad2 NumPad0 NumPad9) for Ñ.
And later, Unicode came along, with thousands of code points rather than 256. And still Windows didn't want to break users' habits, so they kept Alt+numpad digits using a BIOS code point if the sequence of digits is a number between 1 and 255 without a leading 0, and using a Windows code point if the sequence of digits is a number between 32 and 255 with a leading 0 (IIRC control characters in the range 0-31 can't be typed that way). This explains why Alt+(NumPad0 NumPad1 NumPad4 NumPad7) inserts “: it's code points 147 from Windows-1252. Both Windows-1252 and Unicode extend ISO 8859-1, which only defines glyphs for characters in the ranges 32–126 (ASCII) and 160–255. This explains why alt codes with a leading 0 in these ranges match with Unicode, but not for 127-159, where ISO 8859 and Unicode have control characters but Windows code pages added visible glyphs.
When designing alt codes for Unicode characters, the designers of Windows had to pick a mechanism that didn't conflict with the two established mechanisms. Also, Unicode charts use hexadecimal codes, so they couldn't rely on the number pad alone. Alt+(A A A A) means the shortcut Alt+A four times, so there had to be a different way of inserting ꪪ. They picked Alt+(NumPad+ hex digits), where the hex digits can be typed on the main keyboard area.
(Note: I'm not sure if everything in this answer applies to all modern versions of Windows or if some variations or configurations apply. My Windows knowledge is very out of date.)
